# K8s pod unable to access/modified files to NFS Dynamic PV directory without full permission

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, nfsclient

I have written pod yaml and pvc yaml as below and created dynamic provision pod with storage class.
But when pod execute and calling api to access/modified files in PV it gives an timeout exception. Expect to create files with full permission.
PV directory created with full permission. Please find the below pod,pvc and nfs-client-deployment yamls.

*pod.yaml*

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dms
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: dms
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dms
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: dms-repo-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: dms-repo
        - name: dms-log-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: dms-log
      containers:
      - name: dms
        image: xxxx/xxx/dms:3
        env:
        - name: PORT
          value: "61024"
        - name: QUARKUS_LOG_FILE_PATH
          value: "/log/applicationPassive.log"
        - name: REPO_HOME_DIR
          value: "/document/repo"
        - name: REPO_TYPE
          value: "SEGMENT"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 61024
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/document/repo"
          name: dms-repo-storage
        - mountPath: "/log"
          name: dms-log-storage
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: dms
  labels:
    app: dms
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 61024
    name: http
    targetPort: 61024
  selector:
    app: dms
  type: ClusterIP

*PVC.yaml*
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: dms-repo
spec:
  storageClassName: nfs-storage-app
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi

*nfs-client-deployment.yaml*

apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: nfs-client-provisioner-app
  namespace: msdev1
---
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: nfs-client-provisioner-runner-app
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["persistentvolumes"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "delete"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["persistentvolumeclaims"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "update"]
  - apiGroups: ["storage.k8s.io"]
    resources: ["storageclasses"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["events"]
    verbs: ["create", "update", "patch"]
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: run-nfs-client-provisioner-app
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: nfs-client-provisioner-app
    namespace: msdev1
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: nfs-client-provisioner-runner-app
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: leader-locking-nfs-client-provisioner-app
  namespace: msdev1
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["endpoints"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch"]
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: leader-locking-nfs-client-provisioner-app
  namespace: msdev1
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: nfs-client-provisioner-app
    namespace: msdev1
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: leader-locking-nfs-client-provisioner-app
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io


---

apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: nfs-storage-app
provisioner: nfs-provisioner-app
parameters:
  archiveOnDelete: "true"

---

kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: nfs-client-provisioner-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nfs-client-provisioner-app
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nfs-client-provisioner-app
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: nfs-client-provisioner-app
      containers:
        - name: nfs-client-provisioner-app
          image: xxx/xxxx/nfs-client-provisioner:v3.1.0-k8s1.11
          volumeMounts:
            - name: nfs-client-root-app
              mountPath: /persistentvolumes
          env:
            - name: PROVISIONER_NAME
              value: nfs-provisioner-app
            - name: NFS_SERVER
              value: "serveripaddress"
            - name: NFS_PATH
              value: /nfs_srims
      volumes:
        - name: nfs-client-root-app
          nfs:
            server: "serveripaddress"
            path: /nfs_srims

Created files with permission as below.

-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    178688 Jul 16 19:29 data00104a.tar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    160768 Jul 16 19:45 data00105a.tar

This should be change as below full permission to pod api calls working successfully.

-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    178688 Jul 16 19:29 data00104a.tar
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    160768 Jul 16 19:45 data00105a.tar
```

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/issues/260

Comment: Sorry @gohm'c I went through it. But I couldn't able to get it that Which was the solution should I apply. Appreciate share the correct answer.

Comment: @Prabath : Use this [github link](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/issues/260#issue-347296829) issue which is the suitable solution to the full permission to access/ modify  the files.